# How best to translate this .csv with covid19 data to Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm building an api that retrieves time series data of covid cases for each country in nodejs/Express with a mongo DB. The data source is courtesy of [John Hopkins](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv).

For those lazy to hit the link, the headers look like this:

```
Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,1/25/20,1/26/20,1/27/20,1/28/20,1/29/20,1/30/20,1/31/20,2/1/20,2/2/20,2/3/20,2/4/20,2/5/20,2/6/20,2/7/20,2/8/20,2/9/20,2/10/20,2/11/20,2/12/20,2/13/20,2/14/20,2/15/20,2/16/20,2/17/20,2/18/20,2/19/20,2/20/20,2/21/20,2/22/20,2/23/20,2/24/20,2/25/20,2/26/20,2/27/20,2/28/20,2/29/20,3/1/20,3/2/20,3/3/20,3/4/20,3/5/20,3/6/20,3/7/20,3/8/20,3/9/20,3/10/20,3/11/20,3/12/20,3/13/20,3/14/20,3/15/20,3/16/20,3/17/20,3/18/20,3/19/20,3/20/20,3/21/20,3/22/20,3/23/20,3/24/20,3/25/20,3/26/20,3/27/20,3/28/20,3/29/20,3/30/20,3/31/20,4/1/20,4/2/20,4/3/20,4/4/20,4/5/20,4/6/20,4/7/20,4/8/20,4/9/20,4/10/20,4/11/20,4/12/20,4/13/20,4/14/20,4/15/20,4/16/20,4/17/20,4/18/20,4/19/20,4/20/20,4/21/20,4/22/20,4/23/20,4/24/20,4/25/20,4/26/20,4/27/20,4/28/20,4/29/20,4/30/20,5/1/20,5/2/20,5/3/20,5/4/20,5/5/20,5/6/20,5/7/20
```

A typical row:

```
New South Wales,Australia,-33.8688,151.2093,0,0,0,0,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,13,22,22,26,28,38,48,55,65,65,92,112,134,171,210,267,307,353,436,669,669,818,1029,1219,1405,1617,1791,2032,2032,2182,2298,2389,2493,2580,2637,2686,2734,2773,2822,2857,2857,2863,2870,2886,2897,2926,2936,2957,2963,2969,2971,2976,2982,2994,3002,3004,3016,3016,3025,3030,3035,3033,3035,3042,3044,3047
```

I'm trying to model the .csv into a schema that allows for CRUD operations. Having trouble wrapping my head around how each date will dynamically be added on a daily basis.

Currently, I have:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const confirmedTimeSeriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Province_State: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Country_Region: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Lat: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Long: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Records: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
});

const ConfirmedTimeSeries = mongoose.model(
  "confirmed_time_series",
  confirmedTimeSeriesSchema
);

module.exports = ConfirmedTimeSeries;
```

How best should do I design the mongo schema based on the .csv?

Thanks!

Comment: Each record in the schema could be for each date, in that case you can have `Date` and `Count` in the schema instead of `Records`

Comment: So, like this Records: [new Schema({ date: {}, count: String })]?

Comment: That depends on how you will use the data, but Count should be number if you want to analyze it

Comment: @TheeSritabtim, can you reply with a schema model as an answer that I may reference, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are going to use the data, this schema could be a way to implement it.

```js
const confirmedTimeSeriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Province_State: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Country_Region: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Lat: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Long: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Records: [new Schema({
    Date: String, // or Date if you want to do aggregations with the date, but you have to convert the string to a date object
    Count: Number
  })],
})
```